# Using php to create a form that writes user input to a text file

Tags: php, html, forms, text, readfile

I am very new to php (3.5 weeks in) and I am working on a project for a php course I am taking. I have been working on this php file for several days and I am at my breaking point. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

"Create a document with a form that registers bowlers for a bowling tournament. Use a single text file that saves information for each bowler on a separate line. Include the bowler’s name, age, and aver- age, separated by commas. Ensure that the Projects directory has read and write permissions for everyone."

I have successfully created the form and I think I have my variables set up correctly. I am thinking I will need to use an array to store each of the variables based on user input. I have tried writing this and I break everything. Here is what I have so far with my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
       Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>
       <title>List of Bowlers</title>
       <meta http-equiv="content-type"
            content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
       </head>
       <body>

<h1 style="text-transform: uppercase; color: #666666; font-weight: 400; font-size: 1.5em; letter-spacing: 5px;">Register for the upcoming bowling tournament</h1>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_
name'])) {
     $BowlerFirstName = addslashes($_POST['first_name']);
     $BowlerLastName = addslashes($_POST['last_name']);
     $BowlerAge = addslashes($_POST['bowler_age']);
     $BowlerAverage = addslashes($_POST['bowler_average']);
     $NewBowler = "$BowlerLastName, $BowlerFirstName, $BowlerAge, $BowlerAverage\r\n";
     $BowlersFile = "bowlers.txt";
     if (file_put_contents($BowlersFile, $NewBowler,
     FILE_APPEND) > 0)
          echo "<p>" . stripslashes($_POST['first_name']) .
               " " . stripslashes($_POST['last_name']) .
               " has been registered for the upcoming bowling tournament.</p>\n";
      else
          echo "<p>An error has occurred in your registration. Please try again.</p>";
} else
      echo "<p>To successfully enter the upcoming bowling tournament, enter
           your first and last name and click the Register
           button.</p>";

?>

<form action="bowling_names.php" method="POST">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"
size="30" /></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"
size="30" /></p>
<p>Age: <input type="text" name="bowler_age"
size="30" /></p>
<p>Average: <input type="text" name="bowler_average"
size="30" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Register" /></p>
</form>

<?php 

$BowlersList = readfile("bowlers.txt");
echo $BowlersList;

?>
       </body>
       </html>
```

I am really attempting to learn the concepts here. If you are willing to provide assistance, please explain where I am going wrong too. I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: It looks, SE domehow doesn't like questions like yours :-( The main problem with such "concepts" questions that they have a tendency to be 200 pages long without a visible end. A short conceptual answer which is enough for you to continue would be imho a good answer, but I am nearly sure that it wouldn't make you happy. I suggest to start on google, anywhere. You will surely confron a new, more specific problem, then get back with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one issue here with this piece of code:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_
name'])) {
```

and that broken POST array for your "last_name" will prevent it from writing to your file.

It needs to be together:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
```

Then, make sure the text file exists for it, otherwise you'd of gotten a warning such as: (and if your system is setup to catch/display errors, warnings, notices)

> Warning: readfile(bowlers.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory...

Also make sure it has proper permissions to write to it (if it does already exist).

- Usually, 644 is enough. As a last resort, you can use 777 but that isn't a safe setting to use.
- The folder itself also requires proper permissions to write to. 755 is the recommended setting.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Plus right now, your file's content will echo in a single line.

If you want them on seperate lines, you can use the following:

```
$file = fopen("bowlers.txt", "r");

$i = 0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $lines[] = fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);


foreach (lines as $x){
    echo $x.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Just so I understand, I can't have the isset() in my open line of my if statement spill onto a second line? I thought php completely ignores whitespace? What am I missing here?

Comment: @DrewTuzson You're welcome. No, because that just breaks the POST array and is part of a superglobal array and not a standard array. You can have the break where you have your `&&`, just not the POST array itself.

Comment: another unexplained dv (to spite); lovely how people pass by and say shit about a perfectly good answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I can point out:

1) You can't have a line break on this line:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_
name'])) {
```

Don't know if your original code has it, or only the one posted here. If it does, remove it so it reads:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
```

2) The function [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) outputs the file contents directly to the output buffer, it doesn't return its contents, it returns the number of bytes read. So, to read the entire file to a variable you would use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead.

3) I suppose you want `$BowlersList` to be an Array. To achieve that, you need to read the file line by line, then use `explode()` to split each line into an array. Something like this:

```
$fileName = "bowlers.txt";

$BowlersList = array();
if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
    while(!feof($file)){
        $line = fgets($file);
        if ($line != "") {
            $BowlersList[] = explode(", ", $line);
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
} else {
    echo "Bowlers file doesn't exist.";
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($BowlersList);echo "</pre>";
```